# Java application updated to jdk 1.7.25, hit a run time Exception, what's your opinion?

Tags: java, corba

We have a java application recently updated to jdk 1.7.25 from jdk 1.7.21, without any source changed, but hits a run time exception on Windows server 2003. We use OpenORB 1.2 (no more supported) which was provided 10 years ago as a 3rd party library. Here is the trace print:

```
org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: Unable to create CDROutputStream class  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
               at org.openorb.iiop.CDRCodec.encode_value(CDRCodec.java:147)
               at org.openorb.iiop.IIOPServerProtocol.create_profile(IIOPServerProtocol.java:258)
               at org.openorb.net.ServerManagerImpl.construct_ior(ServerManagerImpl.java:697)
               at org.openorb.adapter.poa.POA.create_reference(POA.java:1602)
               at org.openorb.adapter.poa.RootPOA$DomainManagerPOA.create_reference(RootPOA.java:162)
               at org.openorb.adapter.poa.POA.create_reference_with_id(POA.java:1397)
               at org.openorb.adapter.poa.RootPOA.create_poa_domain_manager(RootPOA.java:135)
               at org.openorb.adapter.poa.POA.get_domain_managers(POA.java:848)
               at org.openorb.adapter.poa.POA.create_reference(POA.java:1593)
               at org.openorb.adapter.poa.POA.create_reference_with_id(POA.java:1397)
               at org.openorb.adapter.poa.DelegateImpl.this_object(DelegateImpl.java:121)
               at org.omg.PortableServer.Servant._this_object(Servant.java:79)
               at org.omg.PortableServer.Servant._this_object(Servant.java:98)
               at DPEM.src.presentation.adaptation.adaptationIfc.SessionAdapterPOA._this(SessionAdapterPOA.java:18)
               at DPEM.src.presentation.adaptation.SessionAdapterImpl.<init>(SessionAdapterImpl.java:91)
               at DPEM.src.presentation.adaptation.SessionAdapterImpl.instance(SessionAdapterImpl.java:164)
               at DPEM.src.presentation.adaptation.AdapterFactory.getAdapter(AdapterFactory.java:166)
               at DPEM.src.presentation.adaptation.AdapterFactory.getAdapter(AdapterFactory.java:121)
               at DPEM.src.presentation.dialogControl.DialogController.createAdapterReferences(DialogController.java:320)
               at DPEM.src.presentation.dialogControl.DialogController.<init>(DialogController.java:112)
               at DPEM.src.presentation.dialogControl.PresentationFactory.getDialogController(PresentationFactory.java:470)
               at DPEM.src.presentation.dialogControl.ThreadedClient.run(ThreadedClient.java:136)
```

I couldn't work out further, and I am seeking for java/CORBA expertise advise.

Thank you very in advanced!

Comment: Glad to see someone still using ORB. ;)

Comment: 1999 called and it wants its massively complex  RPC back :) . I am sure you can't do anything about needing to use it but CORBA is pretty much deprecated and there is talk of removing it from the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a long history of incompatibility errors associated with [OpenORB](http://openorb.sourceforge.net/) (see [here](http://marc.info/?l=geronimo-dev&m=110066187714494), [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GERONIMO-448), and [here](http://marc.info/?l=openorb-users&m=107851613002257&w=2)).

This time the culprit is probably this [security fix](http://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/jre-vuln-cve-2013-2446) introduced in JRE 7u22.

Since you are using a legacy library (last update was in 2005) for a legacy technology, I would downgrade the production JDK (as a workaround) and further investigate where exactly things were broken...

Once you find it, maybe there is an easy workaround with no library changes... If there isn't you have two choices:

- Drop CORBA altogether (if you can, this is probably the best road... While I understand that this would be a huge undertaking and that your company may be less than willing to spend money at this, if they want this Software to survive to the end of this decade, now is the time to do something)
- Look at more active CORBA libraries such as [JacORB](http://www.jacorb.org/) (it may get you running with minimal developing effort, but will require extensive testing before you are able to release a production version)

Comment: Thank you Anthony for answer my question. The root cause should be in > JRE 7U21, possible in 7U22 as you mentioned. I still look around to check if can fix if without change to the lib, since additional changes/enhances is not the option due to resource/budge limitation. Thanks again -- Curtis Wu

Comment: Curtis, you are very welcome. If you feel that this is the correct / most adequate answer to your question please don't forget to accept it so that other people within the stackoverflow community can benefit (and of course, to reward me with reputations points... Gold! Gold... - some drooling - Gold!).

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why this isn't working on 1.7.25 with just looking at the stack trace you provided. However I took a glance at the change log of 1.7.25 and one possible thing that can be the problem is the change of Runtime.exec behavior on Windows platform.

Possible workaround:

> In JDK 7u25, the system property jdk.lang.Process.allowAmbigousCommands can be used to relax the checking process and helps as a workaround for some applications that cannot be changed. The workaround is only effective for applications that are run without a SecurityManager.

Also take a look at:

https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/changes_to_runtime_exec_problems
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html

This is just guess, but I hope it'll help you with your problem.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal

:MAIN

           call %DPEM_HOME%\bin\set_env
           set OPNORB_DATA=%OPNORB_HOME%\data
           
           set SECURITY_LEVEL=%SECURITY_LEVEL%

           set WATCH_DOG_SOCKET=48000

           start  /B %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw  -Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbigousCommands=true -DOS_NAME=WINDOWS -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.openorb.CORBA.ORB -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.openorb.CORBA.ORBSingleton -Xmx512m -Xmaxf.2 -Xminf.15 %ADDOPTIONS% -Duser.securitylevel=%SECURITY_LEVEL% -Duser.watchDogSocket="%WATCH_DOG_SOCKET%" %~1

endlocal
:eof

Comment: Thank you Matej, I added in system property as you mentioned above to the start client bat file(actually to the server bat file as well), but it didn't turn any better. I will check more in java source code if there is any place need to give the correct "", also we do have security manager over the system. thanks again --Curtis Wu